# Differentiate between multiple UIButtons with empty titles

Tags: swift, xcode-storyboard

I have a bunch of `UIButton`s (10-15 of them) in one of my Views. I want to display them as an image without the title text, so what I did was set the image for the Button through the storyboard, and then set an empty title for the button.

I want to react differently when each button is pressed. There are a couple of solutions that I can think of off the top of my head, and I'm wondering which would make the most sense, software engineering-wise:

- Each button is connected to a different `IBAction` (too many methods added)
- Each button is connected to a different `IBOutlet` (how to differentiate between the buttons, still? Use `===`?)
- Single `IBAction`, unique tags for each button (this is what I'm doing for now as it's simplest and it works, but aren't tags a bit hacky?)
- Give each button a different title, but find a way to hide the titles, and then connect them all to an `[UIView]` outlet array (is it possible to hide the titles from the storyboard, or must I do it programmatically from the View Controller?)

Comment: I feel like using unique tags is an acceptable approach. It seems much better than the other options for your case.

Comment: If your buttons can be grouped (for instance, button 1-5 should do the same and 6-10 something else) you could subclass `UIButton` and assign it to the buttons. And in your `IBAction` you can check for them with: `if sender is CustomButton { }`.

Comment: Have you tried looking at `tag`s? Many UI elements (at least on OS X) can be given an arbitrary integer. Then, in the `@IBAction` function, get the tag of the tapped object. From there, you can figure out what number does what.

Comment: @Eendje I wish I could do that, haha. Thanks for the input, though!

Comment: @MaddTheSane That's number 3 on the list.

Comment: Well, what you could do is still subclassing `UIButton` and create a name property. This way you can check their `name` and act upon that. I don't see much difference in using `tag` though. Or check their image name and use that as your "tag".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some solutions you thought of are viable, some others aren't (connecting `@IBOutlets` and trying use the equal operator, or hiding the button's title).

I would recommend you to simply **keep using `UIButton` tags (as [that's what tags are there for](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622493-tag)) and use a single entry-point `@IBAction`**. You will then be able to identify each button by their tag.

Subclassing your buttons might seem a bit overkill if you're only trying to identify them...